# hight CPU use realm

Tags: realm

[image]

It Take up more cpu, when using the method

```
[RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:error:]
```

many times

Comment: You probably don't need to use it many times then

Comment: I can't , i need get instance of realm in every i used thread